# How do I set a Fixed Height and Width to a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have looked at a lot of questions that have already been asked and can't find and answer that works for me. I am trying to make a logo that has an ampersand in the middle. The Ampersand is supposed to change font familys every few seconds which works. Only issue is that now when it changes font it messes up the who page.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BVddWV

Main issues are coming from line 21 in the CSS

```
.ampersand{
  display:inline;
  width:35px;
  max-width:35px;
  height:79px;
  max-height: 79px;
  font-family:"Exo", sans-serif;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you want `inline-block` instead of `inline`.

Comment: @Pointy Sadly the problem persists

Comment: You can set `height` for parent `b` tag and make `overflow : hidden` but can't set the fix height for dynamic ampersand.

Comment: I think you should mix position relative and absolute to make that logo keeps its position.

Comment: 35px isn't really wide enough, and one of the ampersand fonts has a weirdly tall height.

Comment: You CAN NOT set width on inline elements. `inline-block`  should do the trick

Comment: Here is the updated pen https://codepen.io/pushpanathank/pen/ERvvGN. Add fixed height for **.logo** container

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Added display: flex on the `<b>` tag and removed ampersand styles and made it a `span` instead of a div and added `line-height: 1` to it.

```
.ampersand {
  line-height: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  transition: all 1s;
}

<b display: flex;>Flo<span class="ampersand">&</span>Behold</b>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var fonts = ['Dosis', 'Exo', 'Gloria Hallelujah', 'PT Sans', 'PT Serif', 'Yaanone Kaffeesatz'];
  var counter = 0;
  var inst = setInterval(change, 2000);

  function change() {
    if (counter > fonts.length) {
      counter = 0;
    }
    font_selection = fonts[counter];
    $('.ampersand').css("font-family", font_selection);
    counter++;
  }
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Molengo');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis|Exo|Gloria+Hallelujah|PT+Sans|PT+Serif|Yanone+Kaffeesatz');
* {
  font-family: "Gill Sans", sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: #f5f6fa;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4% 0px 20px 0px;
}

.logo_text {
  font-family: "Molengo", sans-serif;
  font-size: 70px;
  color: #333;
}

.ampersand {
  line-height: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px 0px 25px 0px;
}

.nav>ul {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.nav>ul>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.nav>ul>a>li {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 20px 30px 20px 30px;
  display: inline;
  transition: border 0.1s linear;
  border: 3px solid #f5f6fa;
}

.nav>ul>a>li:hover {
  border: 3px solid #333;
}

#body {
  padding-top: 35px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper" align="center">

  <div id="header">
    <div class="logo">
      <span class="logo_text"><b display: flex;>Flo<span class="ampersand">&</span>Behold</b>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <a href="#">
          <li>Home</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>About</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>Music</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>Media</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>Contact</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="body"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1st time flickering is coming because of fonts loading on page only when the style is applied. Rest is jerk free. I suggest the user to preload fonts so that the flickering is reduced.

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to set fixed hight for [inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements).

And you need to switch to `display:inline-block` or `display:block` to transform your elements into [block elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements).

Also please note, that some elements like `<span>` or `<i>` are *inline* by default, and some like `<div>` and `<p>` are *block*, but you are still able override that behavior (default) via CSS `display` rule.

In your case (I assume you would like to prevent jumping of your logo text, when *ampersand* changes font), I would suggest two things:

1. set fixed height to the `.logo_text`, you could add `display:block` and `max-height: 84px`;
2. set `ampersand` as `span` not as `div` to make your HTML markup more semantically relevant;